# Getting Syntax error,once we select the option from dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have drpdown boxes and once we select option, that value is pushed to 'arr',so the arr have the following elements,

```
arr=['Self','Spouse''Son','Father','Father-in-law','Mother-in-law','Daughter','Mother'];
```

and Here My requirement is once we select the SON or Father in one select box and if I select 'Mother-In-law' or 'Father-In_law' in another select box, I want alert message like 'In-laws are not applicable'
Here is my code,Here Iam getting the syntax error, can any one look into this,

```
if(($(this).val()=='Son' || $(this).val()=='Father'))
  {if(arr.indexOf($(this).val()=='Father-in-law' || $(this).val()=='Mother-in-law'))>-1){
    alert('In-laws are not applicable');
    return false;}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: post the html of selectbox also

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the error but you are missing a `,` between `'Spouse'` and `'Son'`

Comment: You have one parenthesis to many, in `))>-1`. The syntax error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token >`. That said, the whole logic of the condition seems to be incorrect too. You are passing always `false` to `arr.indexOf(...)`. I don't even understand what you are trying to do there. The nested `if`s don't make sense. If the value is `Son` or `Father`, then it surly cannot be `Father-in-law` or  `Mother-in-law`, so why compare it against those values? You should provide a better example of the whole setup.

Comment: first of all you forget `,` between 'Spouse''Son', also `==` can return `true` or `false`, while indexOf requires integer

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=['Self','Spouse''Son','Father','Father-in-law','Mother-in-law','Daughter','Mother'];
```

should be

```
arr=['Self','Spouse','Son','Father','Father-in-law','Mother-in-law','Daughter','Mother'];
```

Note the comma after 'Spouse'

Comment: @Rajasekhar: I explained what is wrong [in my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399198/getting-syntax-error-once-we-select-the-option-from-dropdown-box#comment25263089_17399198) (you read the comments, right?). But fixing the syntax error will not make your application work. Your logic is incorrect.

Comment: What you mean by `)>-1` ? also what are you trying to achieve ? its really confusing.